# wso2 cluster firewall requirement

Tags: wso2

What are firewall requirements for WSO2 cluster?

I have multicast cluster (ELB 2.0.3, AS 5.1.0, ESB 4.7.0) where I have opened all the known ports in our firewall. I have noticed with firewall off, on one of *worker* node console; when other worker nodes joins/leaves, it announces in the console log. However, same doesn't happens when I enable firewall. I see, it opens random ports in the range 10000 to 99999,i don't know which one to open in the firewall. I wonder if you can give me an explanation about these ports and an idea to what the firewall rules should look like. I would greatly appreciated your assistance.

Thanks,
Jahirul

Answer (score 0):

Ok, port range was a red herring. Firewall needed to allow IGMP packets for multicast cluster.

Comment: Have you tried wka membership scheme? It is recommended in production